# how to get input values in php dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to get input values in `php` array dynamically field add and remove data, increase and decrease field dynamically. I wan to get subject value in array or `json` format in `php` only.

[image: code output]

```html
<div data-role="dynamic-fields">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="field-name">Field Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject[]" id="subject[]" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="field-value">Field Value</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mark[]" id="mark[]" placeholder="Total Mark">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-role="remove">
            <span class="fa fa-minus text-danger"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-role="add">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Remove button click
            $(document).on(
                'click',
                '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="remove"]',
                function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).closest('.form-inline').remove();
                }
            );
            // Add button click
            $(document).on(
                'click',
                '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="add"]',
                function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
                    new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-child').clone();
                    new_field_group.find('input').each(function () {
                        $(this).val('');
                    });
                    container.append(new_field_group);
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="row col-md-12" style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <form>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="AddForm();">Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onClick="DeleteForm();">Delete</button>
            </div>

            <div id="SectionMultipleForm1" class="col-md-12">
                <h5 id="sec_tittle1" style="font-size: 16px; text-decoration: underline;">Form 1</h5>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Field A</label>
                    <input type="text" id="FieldA1" name="FieldA[]" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Field B</label>
                    <input type="text" id="FieldB1" name="FieldB[]" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"> Submit</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <br>
        </div>   
    </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function AddForm(){
        var $div = $('div[id^="SectionMultipleForm"]:last');
        var now = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) ;
        var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;

        $("#SectionMultipleForm"+now).eq(0).clone().prop('id', 'SectionMultipleForm'+num ).insertAfter('div[id^="SectionMultipleForm"]:last');

            //title
            $("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#sec_tittle"+now).attr("id", "sec_tittle"+num);
            $("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#sec_tittle"+num).text("Form "+num);
            //FieldA1
            $("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#FieldA"+now).attr("id", "FieldA"+num);
            document.getElementById("FieldA"+num).setAttribute('value','');
            //FieldB1
            $("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#FieldB"+now).attr("id", "FieldB"+num);
            document.getElementById("FieldB"+num).setAttribute('value','');

        }

        function DeleteForm(){
            var num = $('div[id^=SectionMultipleForm]').length;
            if(num!=1){
                $('#SectionMultipleForm'+num).remove();
            }
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

first at `function AddForm()` find the last div with id `SectionMultipleForm` and get the number

this section at `<script>` is to clone inside id `SectionMultipleForm` and put it after the last `SectionMultipleForm`

```
$("#SectionMultipleForm"+now).eq(0).clone().prop('id', 'SectionMultipleForm'+num ).insertAfter('div[id^="SectionMultipleForm"]:last');
```

and this section change id FieldA,FieldB, and title at the last clone div with id `SectionMultipleForm`

```
//title
$("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#sec_tittle"+now).attr("id", "sec_tittle"+num);
$("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#sec_tittle"+num).text("Form "+num);
//FieldA
$("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#FieldA"+now).attr("id", "FieldA"+num);
document.getElementById("FieldA"+num).setAttribute('value','');
//FieldB
$("#SectionMultipleForm"+num).find("#FieldB"+now).attr("id", "FieldB"+num);
document.getElementById("FieldB"+num).setAttribute('value','');
```

and at the `fuction DeleteForm()` first count how many div have id `SectionMultipleForm` and delete the last div with that id

```
var num = $('div[id^=SectionMultipleForm]').length;
if(num!=1){
    $('#SectionMultipleForm'+num).remove();
}
```